# JUnit - Service Layer - DTO - Error: Argument(s) are different

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, dto

1. I send the Object as a DTO to the Service Layer
2. Here it is concerted to Entity and sent to the DAO Layer:

Service Layer:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addUser(StudentDto newStudentDto) {
    studentDAO.addUser(convertToStudent(newStudentDto));
}
```

The problem while testing is that I need to give a different value to **given** and **when**.

```
JUnit test for addUser()
@Test
@DisplayName("addUser()")
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
public void 
givenStudentObjectDto_whenSavingStudentObject_thenReturnSavedObject() {
    // given -precondition
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    BDDMockito.willDoNothing().given(studentDao).addUser(newStudentTwo);

    // when - behaviour that we are going to test

    StudentDto tempStudentDto = modelMapper.map(newStudentTwo, 
StudentDto.class);
    studentService.addUser(tempStudentDto);

    // then - verify the output
        // Verify how many times the method was called
    verify(studentDao, times(1)).addUser(newStudentTwo);
}

studentService.addUser -> Sends a DTO (that will internally be converted to 
Entity and sent to Dao.

studentDao.addUser -> Receives the Entity
```

It happens that I cannot run the test successfully because I always have this error message:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
studentDao.addUser(
Student{id=0, firstName='Mary', lastName='Jane', email='mj@gmail.com', 
course='Physics'}
);

Actual invocations have different arguments:
studentDao.addUser(
    Student{id=0, firstName='Mary', lastName='Jane', email='mj@gmail.com', 
course='Physics'}
);
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you
Filipe

Comment: studentDAO.addUser(convertToStudent(newStudentDto)); is not the same as: studentDao.addUser(newStudentDto); which is what you do in your test

Comment: use verify with Mockito.any

Comment: verify(studentDao).addUser(Mockito.any());

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stultuske,
studentDao.addUser() -> As an Entity object as parameter
studentService.addUser() -> Receives a DTO object as parameter

They are different Objects because the DTO is converted inside the Service method to Entity.

How can I replicate that for testing?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez, thank you very much. I've spent more than 2 hours trying to solve this...
I've googled about Mockito.any(). It matches all objects that are not null. Is that it?
Edit: It only works with this annotation:
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT).